# Add text to a XML node in F#

Tags: xml, text, f#, xmlnode

This is my XML:

```
<location>
  <hotspot name="name1" X="444" Y="518" />
  <hotspot name="name2" X="542" Y="452" /> 
  <hotspot name="name3" X="356" Y="15" />
</location>
```

what I want to do is:

```
<location>
  <hotspot name="name1" X="444" Y="518">
    <text>
      This is the text I want to add in
    </text>
  </hotspot>
  <hotspot name="name2" X="542" Y="452" /> 
  <hotspot name="name3" X="356" Y="15" />
</location>
```

I'm not able to add the text, no problem with the new node.

Comment: You are leaving out a lot of information. Can we assume you are using System.Xml? What exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with `XmlNode`, I'm assuming you're using the `XmlDocument` type from `System.Xml` (as opposed to the more modern Linq to XML type `XDocument`).

To add a new node with some body text, you can create a new element (with the required name) and then set its `InnerText` value property to specify the text in the node:

```ml
// Load XML document and find the parent node
let doc = XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml("... your xml goes here ...")
let parent = doc.SelectSingleNode("/location/hotspot[@name='name1']")

// Create a new element and set its inner text
let newNode = doc.CreateElement("text")
newNode.InnerText <- "foo"
parent.AppendChild(newNode)
```

You can also write the same thing by specifying the property when calling `CreateElement` like this:

```
doc.CreateElement("text", InnerText = "foo") |> nd.AppendChild
```

Comment: that's right, but does exist a way to have the "text" element not only on a single line but as I wrote in my first post?

Comment: @FrankLioty Yes. If you want to add whitespace (such as new line and some spacing), then you can use `parent.AppendChild(doc.CreateWhitespace("\n    "))`.

Comment: @FrankLioty Check out this property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace.aspx. Maybe that's reformatting your document. If you add whitespace using `CreateWhitespace` and then get `doc.OuterXml` then you should definitely see _some_ (that's what happens on my machine, at least!)